# Cant connect to my live e-mail account with outlook

Tags: windows-8, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, windows-live-mail

I'm using Windows 8 Pro x64, Outlook 2013 x64, and Windows Live Mail account.

For some time, I can no longer access my account. It says "Disconnected" and can't connect.

Windows Phone 7's built-in e-mail client doesn't work either.

https://outlook.com works OK.

testexchangeconnectivity.com tells me "The Exchange ActiveSync settings weren't valid. Additional Details: The Exchange ActiveSync URL was in an invalid format. It should be `https://host/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync`. The URL was https://m.hotmail.com", and displays a link to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33a8eb0f-4dfd-4b4d-a79a-f2e7c0740a43.aspx. Because I'm not an administrator of the Microsoft's e-mail servers, I can't fix the problem.

How do I fix my outlook?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a problem with the Microsoft servers, so it's more than likely that what you're experiencing isn't your fault.
Have a look at the status here: https://status.live.com/detail/outlook